# Issue with build pipeline

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, devops, gitlab-ci

I am trying to implement a CI/CD pipeline as mentioned in this video [by "tech with nana"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qP8kir2GUgo&t=1616s).

But I always end up with [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJ29C.png) which says `-make: command not found`.

[image: error]

However, [I have written in my pipeline code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U65Hv.png) as explained by her in the video.

[image: gitlab-ci.yml]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Check first if your YAML is correctly written.

Typically, `-make` should be `- make` (note the space between `-` and `make`).

The [GitLab pipeline editor](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/lint.html) can help verify the configuration syntax automatically.